# Explain the ondemand CPUFreq governor parameters in SAMSUNG galaxy S4?

Tags: performance, setcpu

I am trying to understand how does the onDemand CPUFreq governor works. I have a SAMSUNG S4 device and I looked into the following file to see the tuneable parameters of SAMSUNG Glaxy S4 GT-i9505 (Qualcomm chipset).

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand

down_differential

enable_turbo_mode

ignore_nice_load

io_is_busy

optimal_freq

powersave_bias

sampling_down_factor

sampling_rate

sampling_rate_min

sync_freq

up_threshold

up_threshold_any_cpu_load

up_threshold_multi_core

I tried to understand these parameters, The kernel documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt
explains Governors and governor parameters, but some of the parameters are not explained in the documentation. Can you please explain or point me to the documentation which I could read and understand all these parameters for a better understanding of dynamic frequency scaling in Android?